# Datasource mat-cell height and data

Tags: css, angular-material, material-design, datasource

I've a problem with datasource mat-cell and data inside it.

- Step 1 : I send a http request to get the first data.
- Step 2 : I send another http request with some parameters from the data of the step 1.

The problem is about data I've got at the step 2. The data go beyond the mat-cell and it's not really beautiful. A screen of my problem :

[image]

> What is the best solution to display all items into the column 3 ?

*Thank you very much !*

EDIT : I add a scroll bar inside my mat-cell with this css code

```
.mat-row {
    min-height: 72px !important;

    .mat-cell:nth-child(3) {
        height: 68px !important;
    }

    .mat-cell:nth-child(3):hover {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your code which doesn't help, but if you want the table to spread out more and the user scroll horizontally then do this to each or some columns:

```
 <td style="width: 10em" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
```

Of course you can use a style sheet and css class to accomplish more.

[Stackblitz Mat Table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-multi-queries?file=styles.scss)

```
<section class='tableSection'>

    <mat-table class="matTable" [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

In the stylesheet:

```
.tableSection {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.matTable {
    width: 40em;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.mat-header-cell{
  text-align: left;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.mat-cell {
  text-align: left;
}
```